# Novel ID: reincarnated in a fantasy world, becomes a merchant

Tags: story-identification, novel, isekai

The novel is about a guy who is reincarnated to another world of magic and swords *maybe a game*. He was born to a noble family or *rich* . This guy knows this world the hero, and he tries to make a plot keep going the right way from the shadow. He becomes a merchant, does missions, and gets strong (he looked for some merchant from the game or novel he knew but didn't find him, so he tries going by his name and look he but up a mask).

He also paid for the hero's sword and asked the the smith to give it to him  after making his. His family doesn't know he is strong or a merchant.
I don't remember if he is a  villain or a mob.

It's not [*Trash of the Count's Family*](https://trash-of-the-counts-family.fandom.com/wiki/Trash_of_the_Count%27s_Family_Wiki) or [*My Death Flags Show No Sign of Ending*](https://www.lightnovelworld.com/novel/my-death-flags-show-no-sign-of-ending) but it's very similar to both.

Comment: Please read our guide https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/4918 for hints for what else to include in your writeup, such as when you read this. Please edit https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/239733/edit details into your question rather than posting them in an answer or comment.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add new details.

Comment: I've fixed a few bits of grammar, but I was uncertain how to parse some of your sentences, like "look he but up a mask". Was the book in English? Did you read it online? On paper? As an ebook?

Comment: novel was translated i read it in English online
the mask its about the mc when he go on missions he change his looks and wear a mask
the mask is the same as the one the character that he is looking for
thanks for the fix

Comment: << A man finds himself reborn in a fantasy world. He knows this world from a game he played in his old life. He becomes a mercenary, going on missions and adventures to make money. He is successful and becomes wealthy. He is searching for a character he knows from playing the game, also a mercenary, but can't find him. He decides to take the character's name and becomes that character. His family in the game world doesn't know he's a mercenary. >>  is what I think the question might mean.

Comment: he start before the game event happen

Comment: What "game event"? And the mall he wears is just a regular mask (bit like one that this other guy wears), not like a realistic face?

Comment: game event like in skyrim when its start  in the wagon he start before his game start 
a and yes the mask is a mask not a a face

Comment: and no the game is not skyrim its jest the only game i can think of the first event in

Answer (score 2):

Clozdark found it in novelupdate. It is [*The Author Reincarnated?! ~I’ll Become an Amazing Villain!~*](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/the-author-reincarnatedill-become-an-amazing-villain/) by Umeda Ryosuke, originally in Japanese.

> Ryousuke, an aspiring light novel writer who posted novels on a free posting site on the internet finally gets his novel, 「Yuusha Tensei 」, turned into a light novel, but on volume one’s day of release, he meets with an accident.
>
> When he comes to, he finds himself in the world of the light novel he wrote,「Yuusha Tensei」.
>
> He has reincarnated as the hero’s greatest rival and the popular villain, Carlo-De-Medici.
>
> This is five years before the hero will be reincarnated.
>
> Ryousuke resolves himself to play the villain perfectly as Carlo, and lead the yet unfinished story of his creation to its ending――

Comment: You can accept your own answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Self-answers have to wait 48 hours from the question time (other answers, it's less than a minute, I think), but that time has passed. Congrats!